# Issues saving PSD as a PDF

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, save

Whenever I save my PSD file as a PDF (see below for links), the bottom 6 bullets on the 1st job title listed do not save on the PDF. Any ideas as to why this would happen and how to fix it?

PSD File: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Bcc333kVTCTkhpNW8wbnVBdEk

PDF File: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Bcc333kVTCODh5ZldYaXZDUzg

Comment: While this is doable in *PhotoShop*, it's not ideal and is the type of job that *inDesign* is much better at. You'll run into less unexpected issues.

Answer (score 1):

This usually means you have an invisible character that PS can't recognize. I did check your PSD and all the layers with problems were `7, 7 copy, 7 copy[n]` so you probably had an invisible character in your layer name, then when you copied it, you reproduced the problem in each layer.

I tried copying your `layer 5` instead, and it worked just fine, which is evidence of a problem in that layer named 7 . I'm not providing the PSD because I'm not sure if it rendered the same (for example, I don't have your linked assets), but just do as I said and it will work.

Additionally, Photoshop uses to have issues when rendering to PDF, so a quick trick to make sure you get the same look is to create a layer by using `ctrl+shift+C` and then `ctrl+v`. This will copy/paste what you see in your document, so PDF will look the same. And of course, you keep editability of document